# Using Min aggregate function on Count aggregate function

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I used this query:

```
 select D.DeptID, D.Dept, count(E.EmployeeID) as TotalStaff
 from Employees as E
 right join Departments as D
 on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
 group by D.DeptID, D.Dept;
```

To return this:

```
DeptID_|_Dept___________|TotalStaff
40     | Marketing      | 2
50     | Accounting     | 3
60     | Manager        | 3
70     | GeneralStaff   | 1
80     | HumanResources | 1
90     | Production     | 0
100    | Sales          | 0
```

Now I want to list the department ID, department and the number of employees for the department that has the lowest number of employees so I tried this:

```
SELECT MIN(mycount) 
FROM 
(
 select D.DeptID, count(E.EmployeeID) as mycount
 from Employees as E
 right join Departments as D
 on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
 group by D.DeptID
);
```

But I get an error that states: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
All I want to do is return the department that has the lowest amount of employees. Please could anyone help me with this.

Comment: use a name for the sub query.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using one I created for an assignment. It has been set as the active database @GordonLinoff

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to write this query is to use the ANSI standard `rank()` function:

```
select d.*
from (select D.DeptID, D.Dept, count(E.EmployeeID) as TotalStaff,
             rank() over (order by count(E.EmployeeID) asc) as seqnum
      from Departments d left join
           Employees E
           on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
      group by D.DeptID, D.Dept
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notice that I also switched the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.  `LEFT JOIN` is generally simpler to follow (at least for people who read languages left-to-right) because it says to keep all rows in the *first* table rather than the *last table*.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the `subquery` alias

So, your subquery has alias like that

```
SELECT MIN(mycount) 
FROM (select D.DeptID, count(E.EmployeeID) as mycount
      from Employees as E
      right join Departments as D on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
      group by D.DeptID
     ) s; -- alias missed
```

Answer (score 2):

please try with below query:

For minimum value:

```
 select min(A.mycount) as min_count
    from  (
         select D.DeptID, count(E.EmployeeID) as mycount
         from Departments as D
         left outer join Employees as E on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
         group by D.DeptID
    ) as A
```

For maximum value:

```
select max(A.mycount) as max_count
from  (
     select D.DeptID, count(E.EmployeeID) as mycount
     from Departments as D
     left outer join Employees as E on D.DeptID = E.DeptID 
     group by D.DeptID
) as A
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
as tablename
```

after your last ) and before the final ;